# How to make mp4 from MediaStream in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ffmpeg, mediarecorder

`MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/mp4')` is `false` in Chrome. So I found `MediaStreamRecorder` https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder then I did

```js
var recorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream, {
  mimeType: 'video/mp4',
});
// also
recorder.mimeType = 'video/mp4';
```

But the output is `webm` as I checked with `ffmpeg -i`

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/Users/otiai10/Downloads/example.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
```

The video is playable in Chrome but NOT on QuickTime Player, in evidence.

[Here](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder/issues/117) are more details and (not!) working example of this problem.

It was said [muaz-khan/Ffmpeg.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/Ffmpeg.js) can convert webm to mp4, but the file size matters.

Is there any workaround to record and save as mp4?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, that was my misunderstanding.

See https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder/issues/117 for more details.

> MediaStreamRecorder can record audio as WAV and video as either WebM or animated gif on Chrome

no mp4 possible.

Comment: is this still true today? thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Crashalot yes, it's still true.

Comment: what about ios 11 that media recorder is not implimented in it?

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [ffmpeg.wasm](https://ffmpegwasm.netlify.app/)

You can install it via:

```sh
# Use npm
$ npm install @ffmpeg/ffmpeg @ffmpeg/core
# Use yarn
$ yarn add @ffmpeg/ffmpeg @ffmpeg/core
```

And then, you can convert your blobs into an mp4 file.
Checkout the example that they provided in the link I shared.

Comment: we need convert mediStream to mp4 , mediaStream is different than blob

Comment: @ghazalehjavaheri As far as I know, it is currently not possible to directly get mp4 from a mediaStream.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it isn't possible to directly record in `mp4`, you can pass the resulting `webm` file to [`webm-to-mp4`](https://github.com/Richienb/webm-to-mp4#readme) to have it converted:

```js
const webmToMp4 = require("webm-to-mp4")
 
const mp4 = webmToMp4(webm)
```

The module can be compiled to work in the browser since it uses [ffmpeg.js](https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js#readme) under the hood.

Comment: This is an interesting concept.  Do you know of any implementations of this? (encoding mp4 direct on the client side browser)?

Comment: This implements a browser-friendly build of ffmpeg so that it will work in the browser.