# MediaRecorder convert blob to MP4 for PPTXGenJS video

Tags: mp4, mediarecorder, webm, get-display-media, pptxgenjs

I'm recording a video stream from [GetDisplayMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia) using [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) to be embedded within a powerpoint document using PPTXGenJS.

I know [MediaRecorder can't record to mp4, only webm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304730), and [PPTX requires MP4 format](https://www.fonedog.com/tricks/powerpoint-codec-unavailable.html).


So the resultant webm blob from MediaRecorder will have to be converted to mp4.

How can I convert the webm blob from `MediaRecorder` to an mp4 blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up saving the webm blob as a file on the file system, then using ffmpeg to convert the webm to mp4, then sending the base64 string representation of the mp4 back to the front end.